# Why does my request fail when I pass an it an object with multiple variables but works but works if I pass it the individual variable?

Tags: reactjs

I have two `vars` `flag1` and `flag2`. Sometimes I use to flag1 to update and others times I use flag2. I want to send an object `obj` with both flag1 and flag2 but it's not working.

```
ChangeData=(flag1, flag2)=>{
  try {
    let obj={}
    obj.flag1 =flag1

    if (!flag2) {
      obj.flag2=flag2
    }
    console.log("LOG "+ payload);
    const response = await serv.patch(`${Myendpoint}/${ev}`, {
      obj,
    })
```

When I send either the var directly, it works just fine:

```
const response = await serv.patch(`${Myendpoint}/${ev}`, {
  flag1,
})
```

This also works

```
const response = await serv.patch(`${Myendpoint}/${ev}`, {
   flag2,
})
```

Comment: What is the `payload ` in console.log ?

Comment: ..and what happend if you send `const response = await serv.patch(`${Myendpoint}/${ev}`, {flag1,flag2,})`

Comment: You should just be sending the object directly, not nested inside curly braces: `await serv.patch(\`${Myendpoint}/${ev}\`, obj)`. Also saying it "doesn't work" isn't helpful. Include the *specific* issue, any error messages and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your endpoint accepts body of the form `{flag1: something, flag2: something}`

Try

```
const response = await serv.patch(`${Myendpoint}/${ev}`, obj)
```

or

```
const response = await serv.patch(`${Myendpoint}/${ev}`, {
  flag1: obj.flag1,
  flag2: obj.flag2,
})
```